# New features added in solr4. 1 version

Tags: solr

`Solr4.1` is a major release after `solr4.0`. Per my understanding there have been some bug fixes, improvements,and new features included in this version. Can anyone please let me know what are the new features will be added in `4.1`?

Comment: I'm sure that any announcements and release notes will be at http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Answer (score 1):

Look for the [Changes.txt](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/CHANGES.txt) for the complete list of changes.

Comment: Thank you.. DIH scheduler also will be added in this?